# Pass List<DerivedClass> to method expecting List<ParentClass> in C#

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I'm creating an app that returns a list of metals to use in various conditions. I have a Metal class then classes for each type of Metal like Steel, Aluminum, etc. If I have a list of different Steels, I want to first select the best ones based on a set of properties common to all Metals then do a second pass based on the unique properties of Steel. (This isn't my exact problem but my problem is analogous.)

I can't figure out how to pass a List<Steel> to the GetBest() method of the Metal class as shown below that takes its first argument of type List<Metal>. The code won't compile due to error at the line highlighted below with **: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Steel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Metal>'.

```
public class Metal {

    public int PropA { get; set; }

    public List<Metal> GetBest( List<Metal> list, int condition1 )
    {
        var best = new List<Metal>();

      //Analysis code here...

        return best;
    }
}

public class Steel : Metal
{
    public int PropB { get; set; }

    public List<Steel> GetBest(List<Steel> list, int condition1, int condition2 ) {

        var bestSteel = new List<Steel>();

      //Do first pass selection based on properties of all metals.
        **bestSteel = Metal.GetBest(list, condition1);**

      //Do some additional analysis based to Steel's unique properties.
      //Analysis code here...

        return bestSteel;

    }
```

Comment: Change `Metal.GetBest` to accept `IEnumerable<Metal>` rather than `List<Metal>`, as `T` is covariant in `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: a `List<Steel>` cannot be treated as a `List<Metal>` since someone could easily add `Tin` to the latter.

Comment: Aside from the covariance problem solved by Johnathan's comment above I think you're probably approaching this problem incorrectly. The logic for picking the best "something" shouldnt be part of the "something" itself but a separate bit of logic.

Comment: What's not clear to me in your example is why, given you have a method which looks like it is there to select a list of the best metals, would you pass in a list of metals in the first place? You never seem to use it.

Comment: @Jamiec - your comment stating that the logic for selecting the best something shouldn't be in that something's class is intriguing and has me thinking. I'm not sure I'll take the GetBest() methods out of the Metal and Steel classes but I'm definitely thinking about it. As for the list of metals passed to the method not being used, the list would be used in the analysis code.

Comment: I just now realized, in my original sample code, I didn't declare the GetBest() methods as static. I intended to and did in my actual code. Nonetheless, the answer provided by @Mureinik seems to solve my problem! Thanks to all for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a constrained generic method:

```cs
public static List<T> GetBest<T>(List<T> list, int condition1) where T : Metal
{
    var best = new List<T>();

    // Analysis code here...

    return best;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer a different question! A look at how I might approach this problem without confounding my objects (`Metal`, `Steel`) with my logic for picking the best metal based on some conditions:

```
public class Metal{}
public class Steel:Metal{}

public class MetalPickerContext
{
    public int Condition1{ get;set;}
}

public class MetalPicker<TMetal, TContext> 
    where TMetal: Metal
    where TContext: MetalPickerContext
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TMetal> GetBest(IEnumerable<TMetal> list, TContext context)
    {
        var result = new List<TMetal>();
        // logic for picking the best metal based on Condition1
        
        return result;
    }
}

public class SteelPickerContext: MetalPickerContext
{
    public int Condition2{get;set;}
}

public class SteelPicker : MetalPicker<Steel,SteelPickerContext>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Steel> GetBest(IEnumerable<Steel> list, SteelPickerContext context)
    {
        var initialResult = base.GetBest(list,context);
        // Having called the base logic apply more with reference to Condition2
        return initialResult;
    }
}
```

This compiles (as you can see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywe3o4)) and I could expand the example a bit given some more details to make it a working one. Let me know if that would help you.